# How get list of all my docs that were created in shared collections

Tags: google-drive-api

I created a lot of docs in shared to me collections. These collections belongs to other users, but files that I created there belongs to me.(I am owner).
I need generate list of all such files with SDK.

Accordingly to [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters):
1. I can get list of all own docs with query = "'me' in owners"
2. List of all shared docs, with query = "sharedWithMe"

Combination of #2 and #1("'me' in owners and sharedWithMe") doesn't work as expected.

Also I can get list of all "sharedWithMe" folders, then loop through all files and subfolders. But this approach is not very efficient.

Is it possible to get list of my files in shared collections with Drive SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a deeper look at [search parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters) and [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).
In search parameter, you would probably want owners, writers, readers, and sharedWithMe.
If I understood your question correctly, this is the query you want.

```
Files.list(q="'{MY_EMAIL}' in owners and sharedWithMe")
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this search query, but it doesn't work properly.